# Polymer deep path binding

Tags: polymer

In Polymer how do I databind to a Deep path property like shown in the example below

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src='bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js'></script>
    <link rel='import' href='bower_components/polymer/polymer.html'/>
</head>
<body>
    <dom-module id='base-page'>
        <template>
            <input type='button' on-click='click'>
            <div>{{item.mydeepproperty}}</div>
        </template>
    </dom-module>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'base-page',
            properties: {
                item: {
                    type: Object,
                    value: function() { return { mydeepproperty: 'default' } }
                }
            },

            click: function() {
                this.item.mydeepproperty = 'woohoo';
            }
        });
    </script>
    <base-page></base-page>
</body>
```

Example also found here:

http://jsbin.com/qonedeleho/1/edit?html,output

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When updating a sub-property of an object, you need to be more explicit in your code to [force a path change notification](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#set-path) and either use the `this.set()` or `this.notify()` function:

```
click: function() {
  this.set('item.mydeepproperty', 'woohoo');
}
```

Comment: Excellent, just what I needed. Thanks